# Is this panel inside my metal trailer/workshop wired safely?

Tags: wiring

I have an old 53' E-Track Semi trailer converted to a shop and have installed a 60A sub panel and run two 15A circuits, 1 for overhead LED shop lights and one for six 4-gang boxes to run minor electrical tools, drills, a grinder & a few small cordless drill chargers.

This is a small 1 man shop that is lightly wired as does not get a lot of use and is on a small homestead-type property. The panel is a 125 amp and I mounted a 60 amp breaker to serve as a main for the sub panel. If this is wrong, somebody show me a diagram w/o changing all of the wiring please. There is no money to completely replace all wiring.

The main panel in my garage is wired directly from the box below the meter base on the pole and the neutral and ground are on separate bars with a #4 conductor to a 10' ground rod. The sub panel inside trailer (all metal trailer) is hooked up with hot to breaker (Black) Neutral (white) to Neutral Bar & Ground to separate Ground bar and run to a separate ground rod outside.

**My concern is when checked with ohm meter that the body of trailer shows as part of ground circuit. Will this shock someone if they touch one of the metal wall ribs on the trailer or the outside skin of it?**

All boxes are metal. I don't care about code long is safe.

The sub panel inside trailer:
[image: sub panel inside trailer]

The main panel is mounted to a 6x6 under the roof outside of the trailer. This is the main panel from the pole:
[image: main panel from the pole]

The label from box being used as sub panel:

[image: Sub Panel Lid Label]
[image: Main Panel AFTER wiring n new Brkr]
[image: Sub panel After Wire & Grnd Hook up]

Comment: Trailer is permanently fixed in place on concrete piers & ICC bumper is 6" in ground on rear & attached 24' x 54' roof attached to 1 side wall.

Comment: Is there a ground connection from the supply to the trailer? There needs to be - "just a local grounding electrode" is not sufficient to meet code for more than 50 years now.

Comment: Can you post photos of the label on the inside of the trailer subpanel's door please?

Comment: Also, which breaker in the main panel at the pole turns off power to the trailer?

Comment: The second picture shows a ground wire from the orange cable connected to a neutral bus, not the grounding bus. That's wrong.

Comment: The trailer itself is grounded by the ICC Bumper (8' 2 x 4 steel bumper wlded to trailer body & Frame) buried in the ground. 12/2 wire from main panel is hooked as shown in pic, Blk to breaker on bus bar, Neutral White to Neutral bar on R side of panel & Bare Ground to seperate ground bar on L side of panel & am going to run #6 bare conductor to 10' ground rod outside if this is what your asking, if not, please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, wire into sub panel is 10/2 not 12/2, I have not installed a main for inside of trailer yet, was figuring on just a 20 amp single pole breaker as draw will be minimal. Mostly just overhead lights 1  grinder & 3 cordless battery chargers running randomly , Sorry it won't seem to let me upload pic of label on inside of panel door. Am fairly new to forums & control+G not seeming to work

Comment: I thank you about the 2nd pic where the ground wire is connected to neutral bus bar, was thinking was wrong wrong. Will change. Thank you. Was in new construction for 20 yrs, but have been out of it for about 20 yrs n a little rusty.

Comment: Figure Blk to 20 amp breaker to run to sub panel, white to neutral bar & bare ground to ground bar & ground bar will be connected by #6 bare to 10' outside ground rod Correct?

Comment: "I don't care about code long is safe." The electrical code's reason for existing is to ensure things are safe. Many parts are written in blood - research into electrical issues has determined that things that used to be acceptable are no longer acceptable because they're not safe. You are 100% concerned with meeting code.

Comment: I do appreciate the help with this, I DO wish that some people WOULD read the description of the problem. The trailer is PERMANENTLY located with an attached roof so tie down breakers aren't necessary. NO arc fault breakers or such in my shop & I have been using the materials I have on hand for a small 1 man home shop on a small homestead type place. The grnd on neutral has been remedied. I know it a 125 amp panel, i put in a 60 amp brkr deliberately & am 80 mi 1 way to any reasonable place to get larger wire. I appreciate the help, but if someone can't be a help, don't be a hindrance.

Comment: If you consider it a "hinderance" when people point out _unsafe_ conditions in your electrical set up, then you're being somewhat hypocritical when you say you only care about safety. Whether you choose to follow the advice offered (and yes, some it too late, like using AL wiring to save money) is entirely up to you, but if one of the unsafe conditions gets you injured or killed, it's on you. There are very knowledgeable people here who are simply pointing out things you may not know. If you don't want the feedback, don't ask.

Comment: @Mudfoot, can you confirm the white wire from the 10/2 in the main panel is not landed on other phase of the double pole 30 amp breaker that is serving the black from the 10/2?

Comment: If you mean the 30 amp in the main panel, 1 is blk & the other is white, it is wired to a 220 volt circuit for my air compressor. If you mean the orange wire on the left of panel, the breaker being used for it is a 20 amp single pole that runs inside the trailer. That 20 controls 2 circuits that control 1 for LED lights & the other for a small bank of outlets.

Comment: I only consider a hindrance that if they read the question some things are totally irrelevant & some things are very helpful. I DO greatly appreciate all of the help & suggestions & have taken them to heart. Hopefully this will help other people also on both good & bad ideas & steer them in the right directions. I primarily wanted to make sure when my 74 yr old wife goes in the garage & turns on a light or whatever I don't find her on the floor. Thanks again & Have a great day.

Answer (score 4):

### 8-space panel

Common mistake (my own cottage had it): the "B" terminal is double-lugged.  It is not rated for double-lugging so that "splitting of the 120V feed" that you're doing needs to be pigtailed.

The panel or its labeling or cover usually provide a numbering scheme. Don't override it, it just gets confusing if you do.

This is actually a 125A panel. (By the way, there is no such thing as a 60A panel. Or 60A wire either - look in Table 310.15(B)(16) :)  Why is that number in our consciousness? Same reason as 110V -- back when power actually was 110V, power companies offered 60A as a service size.)  I mention that because...

[image]

... Weirdly, this panel's main lugs are rated for #4 through 2/0 wires.  I didn't make this up.  They don't specify #10, and they don't have a torque setting for it (but I would guess, 20 inch-pounds).  I would call Siemens to confirm, but technically you may need to pigtail with #4. (!!)   If they tell you that, then just back-feed with a 30A breaker. Those must be installed in spaces 2-4.  A back-feed breaker must have a hold-down kit.

Yeah if I'd known that, I'd have suggested running 4-4-4-6 AL, which is about the price of that 10/2.

If this trailer is moved around a lot, all breakers really should have a hold-down kit.  Or find a legacy PushMatic panel, which uses bolt-down breakers. (that was a special one, to be sure).

Every lug in the panel needs to have its torque set with a torque screwdriver (this is new: NEC 110.14).  I'm not into paying $70 for an actual torque screwdriver and paying to calibrate it annually.  So I'd just go for a [1/4" *beam-type* torque wrench,](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Presa-1-4-in-Drive-Beam-Torque-Wrench-0-21-ft-lb-to-6-67-ft-lb/1002330750) (beam-types never need calibrating), and an extension and *[bit holder](https://www.tekton.com/1-4-inch-drive-x-1-4-inch-hex-bit-holder-sha05102)*.

### 12-space panel

I assume this panel is Square D; otherwise all the breakers are wrong.

It has a back-feed breaker.  This needs a hold-down kit.  That's so you don't accidentally rock it out while working on the panel and suddenly have a breaker with hot lugs in your hand.

The unused red wire, don't bend a wire super tight (can't tell for sure).

A ground wound up on the neutral bar. Easy fix.

By the way if you want a ground bar on the left side or bottom, you can see the holes and "nub" there to mount it.

### On the topic of safety

> "I don't care about code as long as it's safe"

You do a pretty good imitation of caring about Code. The faults I found above were trivial compared to most I see.

But for the record... **they're the same thing.**  If you learn enough about Code, you find out that there are (almost) no stupid rules in Code.  Every one is about safety.  For instance the torque setting rules are because after aluminum wiring had a lot of terminal failures and people blamed aluminum, *they kept happening* with copper. Turns out, torque actually matters on every connection, not just large ones. That's what the science says.

By the way, if we're really talking safety, aluminum wire has been very misjudged. It turns out that the small circuit problems of the 1970s was actually #1 UL failed to properly certify outlets for aluminum wire, and thermal factors caused problems. They found out about that and fixed the aluminum spec. But #2 connection problems *kept happening* on copper wires, and it was traced to improper screw torque. Well, nobody was torquing aluminum small wires *either* back in the 70s.

Meanwhile aluminum heavy feeder #6 and larger has always proven safe, because it was landed on large breakers or subpanel lugs competently rated for aluminum (often made of aluminum), and people always torqued those.

Food for thought next time you need feeder. And that money-savings is brought to you by NEC and the science that drives it!

Answer (score 0):

The trailer metal should be grounded. So that part is fine.

Whether it's **correctly** grounded is unclear from your description.

If you care about safe, you should care about code. Code is "written in blood."